# SQL Finding two duplicated strings

Tags: sql

I want to know if I can find any duplicated rows in such table via query

Like I have table named _stackoverflow with

```
stack1  stack2  stack3  stack4
   1       2      3       4
   1       3      4       5
   1       6      7       8
```

so as you can see, stack 1 got 4x duplicated rows "1"

I want to export the duplicated rows in query order to print me the whole line ONLY if there's smth duplicated. dunno how to explain in proper way. :( I apologize for the mess.

Thanks, ahmed.

Comment: Please clarify: "*stack 1 got 4x duplicated rows "1"*"

Comment: i cannot see, where is your 4x duplicated rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you want to get all the rows where column stack1 is duplicated.
Try

```
Select s.*
From stackoverflow as s inner join
(Select stack1, count(*)
From stackoverflow
Group by stack1
Having count(*) > 1) as dups
On s.stack1 = dups.stack1
```

See  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87876/4

Explanations:
The subquery between parentheses determines the rows with duplicated stack1 column. The result of this subquery is the joined with the original table to grab the entire rows.